# Select site_acr smaller than site_name

Tags: sql, postgresql

list of names(char) and site acreage(int) where site acreage(int) less than First Ave's(char)site acreage

I type this and it doesn't work

```
select ds.dev_site_name, ds.site_acreage
from development_site ds
where ds.site_acreage<ds.site_acreage(select ds.site_acreage where ds.dev_site_name='First Ave')
order by ds.site_acreage desc
```

And that returns only 2 of 4 values

```
select ds.dev_site_name, ds.site_acreage
from development_site ds
where ds.dev_site_name<'First Ave'
order by ds.site_acreage desc
```

Comment: Proper table definitions would be in order here. `\d tbl` in psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't *need* table aliases here at all, since you are only dealing with a *single* table in each (sub-)query:

```
SELECT dev_site_name, site_acreage
FROM   development_site
WHERE  site_acreage < (
   SELECT site_acreage
   FROM   development_site
   WHERE  dev_site_name = 'First Ave'
   )
ORDER  BY site_acreage DESC;
```

If `dev_site_name` is defined `UNIQUE`, you do not need `LIMIT 1` in the subquery.
If it isn't unique, your query is ambiguous and you need to define *which* row you pick from a set of rows with `dev_site_name = 'First Ave'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all sites with an acreage less than that of First Ave by retrieving First Ave's acreage in a subquery

```
select ds.dev_site_name, 
ds.site_acreage 
from development_site ds 
where ds.site_acreage < (
    select site_acreage from development_site
    where dev_site_name = 'First Ave'
    limit 1
)
order by ds.site_acreage desc
```

Comment: It worked when I added ds after development_site - line 5 and limit 1 - line 7 wasn't necessary. The code which worked looks like that:
select ds.dev_site_name, ds.site_acreage 
from development_site ds 
where ds.site_acreage<( select ds.site_acreage
   from development_site ds
   where ds.dev_site_name = 'First Ave')
order by ds.site_acreage desc

Many thanks for help :D